# How to connect and co-process more than two streams in Flink applications?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

How do I decide on how many processElements in Flink application?

This is the structure of my code.

```
<Project>
model 
  Events
projections 
  TestProcess1
  TestProcess2
serializer 
  TestEventDeseriaIizer 
  TestEventSerializer 
util
  NameKeySelector 
FlinkMain
```

If I have three channels I consume from, how do I know how many processElements should I be using? Are we allowed to use only two processElements in Flink applications?

Comment: Any given process function can have an most 2 input streams. Is that what you are asking about? There are various approaches for working around this limitation -- depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. But what if I have more than two input streams? How to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

These techniques can be used to overcome the limitation that Flink's co-process functions and co-flatmaps can only connect two streams:

- Use a SQL join. The joins in the Table and SQL APIs use a special operator that can connect as many streams as you like, rather than just two. (This operator isn't made available from the standard DataStream API because it has some quirks and isn't straightforward to use.)
- Connect the streams in a cascade -- e.g., connect A and B, and then connect C to the result.
- Use `union` to merge the streams. This will require that the streams being unioned all have the same type. If necessary, you can use `Either` to blend two streams with different types (see the [docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/types/Either.html)), or implement your own variant that can combine 3 types together.